# Games that mix emulated old machine code with modern languages

Tags: architecture

Is there any example of game development in a "modern" multi-purpose language (C++, Python, Java, Go) that loads game binaries of an old platform (e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit or 20-bit DOS) and emulates it partially until a given condition and then mixes it with code that runs natively on the host platform?

I am looking for games or extensions of games that use a hybrid approach of emulation and native programming to build newer versions of old games.
I am also not looking for software disassembled and ported to a new system, like SDLPoP.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev! Unfortunately, this "what technology to use" question is considered off-topic here. Also, it's not really specific to gamedev.

Comment: well, you are right. I forgot that I removed all game references and examples, before I posted the question here.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt
I changed the nature of the question, to make clear how it is about gaming.

Comment: That's still unfortunately considered too broad for our scope. For a couple of reasons, "lists of X" questions are considered off-topic here. You may want to describe the issue that you have so that others could help you with solving it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind then. The question then probably doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Helena The real question is what are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you are approaching a problem from the wrong direction and you are asking how that approach would be implemented. A question of "I'm trying to do X, i've done Y and Z so far, but I'm stuck on W" is more on-topic, and more precise on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TomTsagk 
I understand why you look at this as a XY problem. But in this case what I want to do is to see whether approach Y is feasible. 
I tried to ask this question at another place, and the more I described examples of what I would want to do with it, the more people insisted that my approach is wrong, but frankly that is what I plan to evaluate myself.
My plan is to write a library as I described, and I am asking the question to find out whether something like it already exists.
I accept that this is off-topic, if this board is about more concrete problem solving.